# Problem running iPhone application on iPhone from Xcode (and in Instruments)

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments

I have a problem running one application on the iPhone from Xcode (or Instruments).
When I try to run the app I get the error message Failed to upload XXX.app in the bottom left corner of Xcode. The strange thing is it actually uploaded the app to the iPhone but it doesn't start it (after this I can start the app by hand on the iPhone).

So without being able to start the app from Xcode or instruments I have no chance of debugging/performance testing.

Any advice on what might be going wrong here?

The iPhone console shows me this:

```
Thu Oct  1 14:25:18 unknown mobile_installationd[1976] <Error>: 00808e00 install_embedded_profile: Skipping the installation of the embedded profile
Thu Oct  1 14:25:23 unknown SpringBoard[25] <Warning>: Reloading and rendering all application icons.
```

Other applications work fine. I've tried this on two iPhones (both 3.1) with the same result. I am running Xcode 3.2 on SnowLeopard.

Regards

Answer (score 92):

This happened to me as well (more than once). I ultimately had to restart Xcode to resolve the problem (after verifying the code signing settings were correct, the provisioning profile was installed, etc..).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and restarting Xcode solved it. Of course I checked that the right provisioning profile was installed on the iPhone and that the bundle id in the project settings matched the provisioning profile.

Comment: I had exactly this problem today, and as you found, restarting XCode fixed it. This happened around the time I was regenerating Provision profiles multiple times by adding new devices to them.

Answer (score 2):

It says it couldn't install the profile. Check thoroughly your code sign settings and verify after you build the application that the profile you used for code signing indeed the one you chose: go inside the package of the built application, find the embedded.mobileprovision file, open it with a TextEdit application, look for `<name>` tag and see the value. If the value doesn't match the profile you have set in your project, that's might be the reason for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting Xcode solved the problem. While Xcode was running I downloaded a newer version of the iPhone OS via iTunes (v 3.1) and sync (but did not update) the iPhone. My current OS version on the device was 3.0

Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your executable name is set incorrectly.

Expand the Targets group, double-click your target, go to the Properties tab, and check the setting next to "Executable:"

In my projects, it's set to ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}

I think you can also check this in your Info.plist file.